# Selectiong and Asserting 2 or more elements with Xpath - Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So, I'm having trouble asserting some items using selenium.
I have these items that I can use Xpath to locate them:

```
<tr md-row="" ng-repeat="item in vm.clienteContratoFactory.contratos
  | limitTo: vm.clienteContratoFactory.query.limitePorPagina: vm.clienteContratoFactory.query.inicioEm" class="md-row ng-scope">
  <td md-cell="" ng-style="isMobile() &amp;&amp; {'min-width': '150px'}" class="md-cell ng-binding">PADRÃO - COMUM COM TURMA</td>
  <td md-cell="" class="md-cell ng-binding">14/04/18</td>
  <td md-cell="" class="md-cell ng-binding md-numeric">13/05/18</td>

  <td md-cell="" class="md-cell ng-binding md-numeric">R$0,00</td>

  <td md-cell="" class="md-cell ng-binding md-numeric">R$30,00</td>

  <td md-cell="" class="md-cell">
      <md-chips class="no-shadow ng-isolate-scope" tabindex="-1">      <md-chips-wrap id="_md-chips-wrapper-114" tabindex="-1" ng-keydown="$mdChipsCtrl.chipKeydown($event)" ng-class="{ 'md-focused': $mdChipsCtrl.hasFocus(),                       'md-readonly': !$mdChipsCtrl.ngModelCtrl || $mdChipsCtrl.readonly,                      'md-removable': $mdChipsCtrl.isRemovable() }" aria-setsize="0" class="md-chips md-readonly"><md-chip ng-show="item.status == 'Ativo'" class="tiny verde right ng-scope ng-hide" aria-hidden="true"><span translate="" class="ng-scope">Ativo</span></md-chip><md-chip ng-show="item.status == 'Suspenso'" class="tiny azul right ng-scope ng-hide" aria-hidden="true"><span translate="" class="ng-scope">Suspenso</span></md-chip><md-chip ng-show="item.status == 'Fila'" class="tiny amarelo right ng-scope ng-hide" aria-hidden="true"><span translate="" class="ng-scope">Na fila</span></md-chip><md-chip ng-show="item.status == 'Cancelado'" class="tiny vermelho right ng-scope" aria-hidden="false"><span translate="" class="ng-scope">Cancelado</span></md-chip><md-chip ng-show="item.status == 'Expirado'" class="tiny preto right ng-scope ng-hide" aria-hidden="true"><span translate="" class="ng-scope">Expirado</span></md-chip><md-chip ng-show="item.status == 'Trasferencia'" class="tiny vermelho right ng-scope ng-hide" aria-hidden="true"><span translate="" class="ng-scope">Transferido</span></md-chip>        <!-- ngIf: $mdChipsCtrl.readonly -->        <!-- ngRepeat: $chip in $mdChipsCtrl.items -->        <!-- ngIf: !$mdChipsCtrl.readonly && $mdChipsCtrl.ngModelCtrl -->      </md-chips-wrap></md-chips>
  </td>

  <td md-cell="" class="md-cell">
      <a class="md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="" ui-sref="app.clientes.clientesCadastros.contrato-detalhe({idClienteContrato: item.idClienteContrato})" href="#/app/W12HOMOLOG/1/clientes/282//contrato-detalhe/1916">
          <md-icon class="material-icons ng-scope" aria-label="Detalhes">
              remove_red_eye

          </md-icon>
      <div class="md-ripple-container"></div></a>
      <!--<div ng-if="item.idFilial != vm.idFilial">
          <span translate>Filial</span>: {{item.idFilial}}
      </div>-->
  </td>
```

Then I use this to click on , but the script just click on the first  of the tbody list:

```
        var contratoExistente = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='tableHistoricoContratos']/table/tbody/tr/td[1][contains(text(), 'PADRÃO - COMUM COM TURMA')]"))
        //Inicio
        .FindElement(By.XPath(".")).FindElement(By.XPath("//td[2][contains(text(), '14/04/18')]"))
        //Fim
        .FindElement(By.XPath(".")).FindElement(By.XPath("//td[3][contains(text(), '13/05/18')]"))
        //Valor Total
        .FindElement(By.XPath(".")).FindElement(By.XPath("//td[5][contains(text(), 'R$30,00')]"));

    Assert.IsTrue(contratoExistente.Displayed);

    contratoExistente.FindElement(By.XPath(".")).FindElement(By.XPath("//td[7]/a/md-icon")).Click();
```

There is any way to click on the right item on the tr that I want?

Comment: Do you want to `Assert` or `click()`? Which element do you want to `Assert` or `click()`?

Comment: Do you want to click on the element based upon order, so first, second third etc. or do you want to click on it base on the content of the cell?

Comment: click() can solves my problem. So, i use "contratoExistente" as a global var, but exists a list of <tr> and selenium does not locate what I have set as "contratoExistente" and click on the first <tr>